# What is the proper way to implement the lotrproject.com?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, draggable

I am trying to implement something similar to [lotrproject.com](http://www.lotrproject.com/). However, I notice that the site had a lot of lag while interacting with it (dragging). Chrome's task manager shows as much as 11%+ CPU usage while interacting. Is this normal? OR is this site implement improperly? I noticed that this site has all it's content in a single div.

```
<div id="zoomcontent" class="images ui-draggable" style="width: 15358px; height: 5326.6666666667px; left: -6907px; top: -654px;">
<!-- CONTENT -->
</div>
```

Google maps on the other hand uses something like -

```
<div id="dragContainer" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 0; -webkit-transform: translate(-4482px, -3928px) scale(1);">
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 0;">
            <img src="https://mts0.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@26..." class="css-3d-layer" style="position: absolute; left: 7359px; top: 6211px; width: 256px; height: 256px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
            <!-- MORE IMGs -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and scrolling the maps does not increase the size of the body. I suspect a very large DOM shall slow down the browser and cause lags while interacting. Is there a better way to implement lotrproject without a very large DOM?

Comment: 11%?  That's amazingly low.  Most of these sorts of pages are pegged at 100% the whole time.  This site has some serious issues though.  I can't drag around without selecting things by accident.  And then if you use the browser's scrollbars, the internal drag location is off.  If you don't want a large DOM, you can add/remove items, but I don't see any issue with the size of the DOM on this page.

Comment: I have got this http://bharath.lohray.com/_beta_/ft/ for now, it is under development and might be broken or different each time you see it.